# getting rid of Insert trigger

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

Trying to explore solutions alternative to using insert triggers. Like API based ones and pros and cons with different approaches.

Comment: If you want us to show some code, please start by showing what you have so far.

Comment: And perhaps the trigger just needs to be performance tuned.

Answer (score 3):

In an API approach you would create a procedure to perform both operations - something like:

```
package body emp_api is

    procedure insert_emp (...) is
    begin
        insert into emp (...) values (...);
        -- Insert that was previously in trigger
        insert into other_table (...) values (...);
    end;
end;
```

Then you **force** applications to use the API by giving them EXECUTE access to the api package but no INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE access to the tables.

Comment: Of course, you would need to measure to make sure this approach was actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee that you'll have a record inserted into tableB when something inserts into tableA, then keep the trigger.  You can disable if bulk loading into tableA and can guarantee you'll have the only process loading into that table during that time.

As soon as you remove the trigger, you have NO guarantees about inserts into tableB.  Your only hope is that any and all programs that may insert into tableA (do you really know all of these?) adhere to the secondary insert into tableB.  This is "data integrity via company policy", not data integrity enforced via Oracle.

This approach depends on how much you care about the state of the data in tableB I suppose.

I would NOT go the route of table apis (TAPIs), which now force any/all operations through some pl/sql api that handles the logic.  These almost always tend to be slow and buggy in my experience.

Comment: Not sure whether you were referring to my answer, but I don't advocate TAPIs either.  I advocate transaction APIs, sometimes called XAPIs.  I am rather anti-triggers, though not for simple uses such as in the question particularly.

Comment: @tony, I still would avoid an approach that forces all DML through a procedure

Answer (score 0):

In DDL You can disable a trigger with ALTER TRIGGER or ALTER TABLE.

```
ALTER TRIGGER triggername DISABLE;  -- disable a single trigger

ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS; -- disable all triggers on a table
```

To do this at runtime, you would have to use dynamic SQL and the schema in which the procedure is running must own the table or otherwise have the necessary privileges.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER tablename DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS';
```

For more info on enabling/disabling triggers, see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general004.htm